# Compilation blocked with tikz

Tags: tikz-external

I'm writing figure with several segments, and it looks like tikz does not like it. So I added:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows} 
\tikzexternalize
```

It worked well, and sudenly if I had only one more arc, compilation is blocked.

```
\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

If I look in myFigure.log, I cannot see anything wrong. It ends with

```
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is availabl
```

Since I do not have any error message, I really do not know where to look for.

Here is an example of 2 figures that do not compile on my system:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dcucite,abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\tikzexternalize

\textwidth 150mm \textheight 230mm \topmargin -20mm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\marginparwidth 17mm
\oddsidemargin 7mm
\newcommand{\cvd}{\hfill\raisebox{3pt}{\fbox{\rule{0mm}{1mm}\hspace*{1mm}\rule{0mm}{1mm}}\,} \vspace{5mm}}
\newcommand{\proof}{\vspace{1mm}\noindent{\it Proof}\quad}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\newcounter{bean}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[h]\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
init/.style={
  draw,
  circle,
  inner sep=2pt,
  font=\Huge,
}]
\matrix[row sep= 5mm, column sep=8mm] (m) {
\node [init] (x0) {}; & \node [init] (x1) {}; & \node[init] (x2) {}; & \node[init] (x3) {}; & \node[init] (x4) {}; & \node[init] (x5) {}; & \node[init] (x6) {}; & \node[init] (x7) {};\\
\node [init] (y0) {}; & \node [init] (y1) {}; & \node[init] (y2) {}; & \node[init] (y3) {}; & \node[init] (y4) {}; & \node[init] (y5) {}; & \node[init] (y6) {}; & \node[init] (y7) {};\\
\node [init] (z0) {}; & \node [init] (z1) {}; & \node[init] (z2) {}; & \node[init] (z3) {}; & \node[init] (z4) {}; & \node[init] (z5) {}; & \node[init] (z6) {}; & \node[init] (z7) {};\\
};

\node [init, left=of m] (s) {$s$};

\node [init, right=of m] (e) {$e$};

\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x0);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y0);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z0);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x1);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y1);
\path (s) edge[->, thick] (z1);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y2);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z2);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y3);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z3);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y4);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y5);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z5);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x6);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
%\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z7);

\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (x1);
\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (y1);
\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (z1);
\path (y0) edge[->, dotted] (x1);
\path (y0) edge[->, dotted] (y1);
\path (y0) edge[->, dotted] (z1);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (x1);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (y1);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (z1);

\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (y2);
\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (z2);
\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (y2);
\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (z2);
\path (z1) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
\path (z1) edge[->, thick] (y2);
\path (z1) edge[->, dotted] (z2);

\path (x2) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
\path (x2) edge[->, dotted] (y3);
\path (x2) edge[->, dotted] (z3);
\path (y2) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
\path (y2) edge[->, thick] (y3);
\path (y2) edge[->, dotted] (z3);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (y3);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (z3);

\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (y4);
\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
\path (y3) edge[->, thick] (y4);
\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (y4);
\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (z4);

\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (y5);
\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (z5);
\path (y4) edge[->, thick] (x5);
\path (y4) edge[->, thick] (y5);
\path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (z5);
\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (y5);
\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (z5);

\path (x5) edge[->, thick] (x6);
\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
\path (y5) edge[->, thick] (x6);
\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (x6);
\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (z6);

\path (x6) edge[->, thick] (x7);
\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (z7);
\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (z7);
\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (z7);

\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y0) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z1) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x2) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y2) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x7) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (x7) edge[->, thick] (e);
\path (z7) edge[->, dotted] (e);

\node [left=of x0, xshift=-1cm] (A1) {A};
\node [left=of y0, xshift=-1cm] (A2) {B};
\node [left=of z0, xshift=-1cm] (A3) {C};

\node [above=of A1] (types) {Title 1};
\node [above=of m] (types) {Title 2};

\node [below=of z0, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{a}};
\node [below=of z1, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{b}};
\node [below=of z2, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{c}};
\node [below=of z3, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{d}};
\node [below=of z4, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{e}};
\node [below=of z5, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{f}};
\node [below=of z6, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{g}};
\node [below=of z7, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{h}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
init/.style={
  draw,
  circle,
  inner sep=2pt,
  font=\Huge,
  %join = by -latex
}]
\matrix[row sep= 5mm, column sep=8mm] (m) {
\node [init] (x0) {}; & \node [init] (x1) {}; & \node[init] (x2) {}; & \node[init] (x3) {}; & \node[init] (x4) {}; & \node[init] (x5) {}; & \node[init] (x6) {}; & \node[init] (x7) {};\\
\node [init] (y0) {}; & \node [init] (y1) {}; & \node[init] (y2) {}; & \node[init] (y3) {}; & \node[init] (y4) {}; & \node[init] (y5) {}; & \node[init] (y6) {}; & \node[init] (y7) {};\\
\node [init] (z0) {}; & \node [init] (z1) {}; & \node[init] (z2) {}; & \node[init] (z3) {}; & \node[init] (z4) {}; & \node[init] (z5) {}; & \node[init] (z6) {}; & \node[init] (z7) {};\\
};

\node [init, left=of m] (s) {$s$};

\node [init, right=of m] (e) {$e$};

\path (s) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{7}} (x0);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{1}} (y0);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{2}} (z0);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x1);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (e);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z1);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z2);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z3);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z5);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x6);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (z7);

\path (x0) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{7}} (x1);
\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (y1);
\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (z1);
\path (y0) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{7}} (x1);
\path (y0) edge[->, dotted] (z1);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{7}} (x1);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (y1);
\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (z7);

\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
\path (x1) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{1}} (y2);
\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (z2);
\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
\path (y1) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{1}} (y2);
\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (z2);
\path (z1) edge[->, dotted] (x2);
\path (z1) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{1}} (y2);

\path (x2) edge[->, dotted] (y3);
\path (x2) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{2}} (z3);
\path (y2) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
\path (y2) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{2}} (z3);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (x3);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (y3);
\path (z2) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{2}} (z3);

\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (y4);
\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
%\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (y4);
\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (x4);
\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (y4);
%\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (z4);
%
%\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (y5);
\path (x4) edge[->, dotted[ (z5);
\path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
%\path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (y5);
\path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (z5);
%\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (x5);
%\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (y5);
%\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (z5);
%
%\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (x6);
%\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
%\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
%\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (x6);
%\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
%\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
%\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (x6);
%\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (y6);
%\path (z5) edge[->, dotted] (z6);
%
%\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
%\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
%\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (z7);
%\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
%\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
%\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (z7);
%\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (x7);
%\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (y7);
%\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (z7);
%
%\path (x0) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y0) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z0) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (x1) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y1) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z1) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (x2) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y2) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z2) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (x3) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y3) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z3) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (x4) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z4) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (x5) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y5) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z5) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{0}} (e);
%\path (x6) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (y6) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (z6) edge[->, dotted] (e);
%\path (x7) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{0}} (e);
%\path (y7) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{0}} (e);
%\path (z7) edge[->, dotted, very thick] node {\textbf{0}} (e);

\node [left=of x0, xshift=-1cm] (A1) {A};
\node [left=of y0, xshift=-1cm] (A2) {B};
\node [left=of z0, xshift=-1cm] (A3) {C};

\node [below=of z0, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{a}};
\node [below=of z1, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{b}};
\node [below=of z2, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{c}};
\node [below=of z3, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{d}};
\node [below=of z4, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{e}};
\node [below=of z5, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{f}};
\node [below=of z6, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{g}};
\node [below=of z7, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{h}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This creates files test-figure0.dep, .dpth, .log, .md5 and .pdf, but for figure1, there are all but PDF.
I use TeXShop to compile with 'pdflatex -shell-escape' as the default command

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did it. I hope it will help.

Comment: I don't think you took *minimal* literally. You should.

Comment: It is minimal. It is long just because I add a lot of edges. It's only 2 figures on one page without any text. The problem comes from the number of edges, so to reproduce the problem, I need to copy all edges. And I put extra edges in comment, so people can add more edges easily if it does not reproduce the problem on their machine.

Comment: If I remove only one edge on this figure, it does not compile to the end.

Comment: I can comment out the tizexternalize and it still loops , it is stuck on `l.264 \path (y4) edge[->, dotted] (x5)`  as if you pause it with control-c that's where it is, and if you set it going and stop it later, it's still there

Comment: In my case, it seems that this is related to the externalization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the excessive number of `edge` in your second figure which somehow (I dind't find the exact reason), freezes the compiler, without producing any "out of memory" error.

Externalizing the figure won't help, because after all pdflatex has to be invoked anyway over the external figure, which freezes the compiler again.

Two strategies can improve the code and the compilation:

1. Instead of `\path (a) edge[options] (b);`, use `\draw[options] (a) -- (b);` Using draw instead of edge reduces memory consumption (I don't know why)
2. Use loops! Even if I cannot think any reason for which this would reduce the memory consumption, at least it would make the code shorter, more readable and maintainable.

This is my take on the second figure.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ 
init/.style={ 
  draw, 
  circle, 
  inner sep=2pt, 
  font=\Huge, 
  %join = by -latex 
}] 
\matrix[row sep= 5mm, column sep=8mm] (m) { 
\node [init] (x0) {}; & \node [init] (x1) {}; & \node[init] (x2) {}; & \node[init] (x3) {}; &             → \node[init] (x4) {}; & \node[init] (x5) {}; & \node[init] (x6) {}; & \node[init] (x7) {};\\ 
\node [init] (y0) {}; & \node [init] (y1) {}; & \node[init] (y2) {}; & \node[init] (y3) {}; &             → \node[init] (y4) {}; & \node[init] (y5) {}; & \node[init] (y6) {}; & \node[init] (y7) {};\\ 
\node [init] (z0) {}; & \node [init] (z1) {}; & \node[init] (z2) {}; & \node[init] (z3) {}; &             → \node[init] (z4) {}; & \node[init] (z5) {}; & \node[init] (z6) {}; & \node[init] (z7) {};\\ 
}; 

\node [init, left=of m] (s) {$s$};     
\node [init, right=of m] (e) {$e$}; 

\foreach \start/\end/\label in { 
    s/x0/7,  s/y0/1,  s/z0/2, 
    x0/x1/7, y0/x1/7, z0/x1/7, 
    x1/y2/1, y1/y2/1, z1/y2/1,
    x2/z3/2, y2/z3/2, z2/z3/2 } {
        \draw[->,dotted,very thick] (\start) -- (\end) node[midway] {\textbf{\label}};
};
\foreach \n [count=\previous from 0] in {1,...,7} {
    \draw[->,dotted] (s) -- (x\n);   \draw[->,dotted] (x\n) -- (e);
    \draw[->,dotted] (s) -- (z\n);   \draw[->,dotted] (z\n) -- (e);
    \draw[->,dotted] (x\previous) -- (y\n);
    \draw[->,dotted] (x\previous) -- (z\n);
    \draw[->,dotted] (y\previous) -- (x\n);
    \draw[->,dotted] (y\previous) -- (z\n);
    \draw[->,dotted] (z\previous) -- (x\n);
    \draw[->,dotted] (z\previous) -- (y\n);
}
\path (s) edge[->, dotted] (e);

\node [left=of x0, xshift=-1cm] (A1) {A};
\node [left=of y0, xshift=-1cm] (A2) {B};
\node [left=of z0, xshift=-1cm] (A3) {C};

\foreach \letter [count=\n from 0]in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} {
    \node [below=of z\n, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.5cm]  {\rotatebox{60}{\letter}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code compiles without problems and in a short time it produces:

[image: Result]

## Update

Noticed some missing edges (well, I'm not sure about what is the intended figure), and one opportunity to compact even more the code with inner loops, in the part which draws the miriad of little edges between nodes:

```
\foreach \n [count=\previous from 0] in {1,...,7} {
    \draw[->,dotted] (s) -- (x\n);   \draw[->,dotted] (x\n) -- (e);
    \draw[->,dotted] (s) -- (z\n);   \draw[->,dotted] (z\n) -- (e);
    \foreach \s in {x,y,z} {
       \foreach \e in {x,y,z} {
          \draw[->,dotted] (\s\previous) -- (\e\n);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is now:

[image: New result]